# React Application. Submit button is only returning "type" and not the actual value submitted to it

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want this application to be able to add a new animal object but when i console.log to see the output of my handle submit function it returns the string "type". Ive narrowed down the bug to be in my map method that returns the animal type: value='type'>{type}
but im unsure what to replace here to get the desired output of whats submitted

```
handleSubmit(e) {
    console.log(this.refs.type.value)
    e.preventDefault()
}

render() {
let typeOptions = this.props.types.map(type => {
    return (<option key={type} value='type'>{type}</option>)
})
 return (
   <div>
     <h3>Add an Animal</h3>
     <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}>
         <div>
             <label>Species</label><br />
             <input type='text' ref='species' />
        </div>
        <div>
             <label>Type</label><br />
             <select ref="type" >
                {typeOptions}
             </select>
        </div>
        <input type='submit' value='submit' />
    </form>
 </div>
```

Comment: You set all the options values to type in ` return (<option key={type} value='type'>{type}</option>)` it should be the value from the map.

Comment: **Voting to close as typo/non-repro/not-useful-to-others-in-future**. `value='type'` sets the value to the string `type`. It doesn't *use* type. If you want the actual type, you want `value={type}` (just as you've done with `key` and in other places).

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> return (<option key={type} value='type'>{type}</option>)
>                 ^^ 1       ^^ 2          ^^ 3
> ```

1. What is this `key` attribute? [It does not exist in HTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option). Get rid of it
2. Look here. You have set the value to be the *hard-coded string* `'type'`. Don't do that. Use a variable.
3. Here you've used a variable. Do the same thing for the value attribute.

Comment: `key` is a React thing, and should be there when rendering lists of elements. (Whether its value should be `type` depends on whether `type` is unique in the list, but it probably is.)